# Normalize space in each element of XML using XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am having am XML like this -

```
<a:price-range xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core" xmlns:f="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/fields" xmlns:a="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/assets" xmlns:r="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/refdata">
    <c:id>
        http://iddn.icis.com/series-item/petchem/4021090-pricehistory-19990730000000</c:id>
    <c:type>series-item</c:type>
    <f:assessment-low>8.946586935</f:assessment-low>
    <f:assessment-high>9.946586935</f:assessment-high>
    <f:mid>9.44658693500000000000</f:mid>
    <f:period-label>
        <c:l10n xml:lang="en"/>
    </f:period-label>
</a:price-range>
```

I want to normalise the space in the XML. Like in above example, there are spaces in *c:id* element. After normalising spaces, above XML will look like -

```
<a:price-range xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core" xmlns:f="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/fields" xmlns:a="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/assets" xmlns:r="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/refdata">
    <c:id>http://iddn.icis.com/series-item/petchem/4021090-pricehistory-19990730000000</c:id>
    <c:type>series-item</c:type>
    <f:assessment-low>8.946586935</f:assessment-low>
    <f:assessment-high>9.946586935</f:assessment-high>
    <f:mid>9.44658693500000000000</f:mid>
    <f:period-label>
        <c:l10n xml:lang="en"/>
    </f:period-label>
</a:price-range>
```

I had a look at [fn:normalise-space](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:normalize-space), but it work for strings only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function worked fine for me -

```
(:
  The rules/assumptions are:
  #1 Retain one leading space if the node isn't first, has non-space content, and has leading space.
  #2 Retain one trailing space if the node isn't last, isn't first, and has trailing space. 
  #3 Retain one trailing space if the node isn't last, is first, has trailing space, and has non-space content.
  #4 Retain a single space if the node is an only child and only has space content.
  :)
  declare function local:normalize-space-in-xml($input)
  {
     element {node-name($input)}
       {$input/@*,
         for $child in $input/node()
         return
           if ($child instance of element())
           then local:normalize-space-in-xml($child)
           else
             if ($child instance of text())
             then
               (:#1 Retain one leading space if node isn't first, has non-space content, and has leading space:)
               if ($child/position() ne 1 and matches($child,'^\s') and normalize-space($child) ne '')
               then (' ', normalize-space($child))
               else
                 (:#4 retain one space, if the node is an only child, and has content but it's all space:)
                 if ($child/last() eq 1 and string-length($child) ne 0 and normalize-space($child) eq '')
                 (: this overrules standard normalization:)
                 then ' '
                 else
                   (:#2 if the node isn't last, isn't first, and has trailing space, retain trailing space and collapse and trim the rest:)
                   if ($child/position() ne 1 and $child/position() ne last() and matches($child,'\s$'))
                   then (normalize-space($child), ' ')
                   else
                     (:#3 if the node isn't last, is first, has trailing space, and has non-space content, then keep trailing space:)
                     if ($child/position() eq 1 and matches($child,'\s$') and normalize-space($child) ne '')
                     then (normalize-space($child), ' ')
                     (:if the node is an only child, and has content which is not all space, then trim and collapse, that is, apply standard normalization:)
                     else normalize-space($child)
              else $child
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible by applying serialization options, you have to go through the tree applying the [transformation pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Filtering_Nodes). A slightly adjusted example from that page to normalize space and support namespaces:

```
declare function local:copy($node as node()) as node() {
  typeswitch($node)
    case $text as text()
      return text { normalize-space($text) }
    case $element as element()
      return
        element { QName(namespace-uri($element), name($element)) } {
                  $element/@*,
                  for $child in $element/(* | text()) return local:copy($child)
                }
    default return $node
 };


local:copy(
  <a:price-range xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core" xmlns:f="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/fields" xmlns:a="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/assets" xmlns:r="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/refdata">
    <c:id>
        http://iddn.icis.com/series-item/petchem/4021090-pricehistory-19990730000000</c:id>
    <c:type>series-item</c:type>
    <f:assessment-low>8.946586935</f:assessment-low>
    <f:assessment-high>9.946586935</f:assessment-high>
    <f:mid>9.44658693500000000000</f:mid>
    <f:period-label>
        <c:l10n xml:lang="en"/>
    </f:period-label>
  </a:price-range>
)
```

Marklogic also allows to [apply an XSLT stylesheet](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/enhanced#id_56907), which might be the more elegant version of doing so using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as proposed by @Raj.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` work perfect and you need to first transform xml to xml through xslt.

Comment: Spaces can be in any element.  c:id is just an example. A method which can normalise spaces in the whole XML is needed in this case.

Comment: Secondly, I am looking for a solution in XQuery, rather then in XSLT.

Comment: xsl:strip-space only removes text nodes consisting entirely of white space. It does not remove leading and trailing white space from nodes that also contain printable text.